# Why is google colab not allowing me to add data to a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-colaboratory

I am trying to load a file in a `pandas dataframe` in `google colab` and then in a `for loop`, I'm adding data in the `csv` file using

```
for i in range(100):
  res=some_processing()
  df.loc[len(df)] = [i,res]
  df.to_csv(df)
```

It was working fine yesterday and I was able to store all the values yesterday in the csv file. But today, it's `not moving beyond index 75`. some_processing() takes around 10 mins every time. So, I let it run for a long time. But I noticed that it `didn't store value` for the last 25 or something. It just stored upto 75 values and no, it's not because google colab shut down. I check for the values that are already done so i just skip them if they are there. So, now when I start this program, it runs from 75 then after 10 mins, I checked the csv in my drive file and `it had the 76th entry written`. So, I stopped the program and let it run again. This time it skipped the 76th entry but after another 10 mins, when I checked the csv file, the `77th value had overwritten the 76th value`. Now, when I ran it again, the 76th value overwrote 77th value. So, the cycle continues. I don't understand why this is happening. It was working fine yesterday and I was able to store upto 130 values when I wanted. It's like len(df) got stuck or something. and also 1 more thing, when I tried to manually add values to the dataframe and then store it, it was working fine too. I don't know what's happening.

Comment: How did you skip them? Did you run from range 75 or check if it exists? Also, I would use append if I am adding records to a DataFrame.

Comment: By a simple `if i in list(df['serial number']): continue`